# Why do I need to escape dollar sign even with grep -F

Tags: grep

```
# minimal example file
printf "hey\$you\nhey\$me\n" > test
cat test
# hey$you
# hey$me
```

Simple `grep` on it:

```
grep -F "hey$you" test
# hey$you
# hey$me
```

i.e., both lines are matched when only the first should be.

If I escape `$`, it works as intended:

```
grep -F "hey\$you" test
# hey$you
```

However, this goes against my understanding of `-F`/`--fixed-strings`

> Interpret pattern as a set of fixed strings (i.e. force `grep` to behave as `fgrep`).

There's also nothing in `man fgrep` about `$` in particular.

Reproduced on macOS and Ubuntu

Comment: You are escaping the `$` signs *for the shell*, not for grep. When grep gets to see the arguments they have already been processed by the shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *shell* is expanding `$you` as a (likely empty) variable because you used "weak" (double) quoting.

You can confirm this by setting the shell's `x` option:

```
$ grep -F "hey$you" test
+ grep --color=auto -F hey test
# hey$you
# hey$me
```

As you can see, `"hey$you"` becomes simply `hey` - which matches both lines.

In contrast, with strong (single) quotes around the pattern:

```
$ grep -F 'hey$you' test
+ grep --color=auto -F 'hey$you' test
# hey$you
```

Comment: Ah, subtle. Makes perfect sense, thanks.